# CCNet - Automatically force prerequisite build

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

If I have two builds, A and B, how can I set up CCNet such that when B is forced, it will automatically force a build for A before proceeding with the build steps for B?

I've seen the ForceBuildPublisher, however that looks like it's for dependent builds instead of prerequisite builds.

I've also seen the page for the "launchccnetbuild" nant task, but the code file appears to be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No "nice" way, I am afraid. ForceBuildPublisher will work if you can make project B wait for project A to start and **finish**. For the latter multiple possiblities exist, one would be to poll a file.

Answer (score 0):

As Lothar_K mentioned that there is no "nice" way. Usually when this situation is needed then the build scripts(in your case nant task) from Build A is copied\merge to the nant task from Build B.

Another route is to use [sequential task](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Sequential+Task) depending on your CCNet version.